# How to use Google Identity Services JavaScript SDK with Vue / TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, google-oauth

I'm trying to authorize some Google APIs using the new Google Identity Services JavaScript SDK in my Vue / Quasar / TypeScript app.

As [per the docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/load-3p-authorization-library) I have loaded the Google 3P Authorization JavaScript Library in the header of my `index.template.HTML` file like so:

```JavaScript
<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" onload="console.log('TODO: add onload function')">  
</script>
```

Now inside a Vue component I have this:

```Vue
<template>
  <v-btn
    class="q-ma-md"
    design="alpha"
    label="Connect Google Calendar"
    @click="handleGoogleCalendarConnect"
  />
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import VBtn from 'src/components/VBtn.vue';

const client = google.accounts.oauth2.initCodeClient({ // <-- TypeScript Error Here
  client_id:
    'MY_CLIENT_API_KEY_GOES_HERE',
  scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly',
  ux_mode: 'popup',
  callback: (response: any) => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', code_receiver_uri, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    // Set custom header for CRSF
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XmlHttpRequest');
    xhr.onload = function () {
      console.log('Auth code response: ' + xhr.responseText);
    };
    xhr.send('code=' + code);
  },
});

const handleGoogleCalendarConnect = () => {
  client.requestCode();
};
</script>
```

But I am getting a TypeScript error on "google" that says: `Cannot find name 'google'. ts(2304)`

Maybe it's because I'm missing types for the Google Identity Services JavaScript SDK? If so, where to find them?

Or perhaps the problem is something else?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Found the correct type package:

`npm i @types/google.accounts`

This removes the error.

Comment: Hello, I am trying to use this typings file in my Vue application but installing the package did not work for me. I have also added "google.accounts" to my types in tsconfig.json, and added `/// <reference types="google.accounts" />` to the relevant file, but I just continue to get the `google is not defined error` when I try to use it, any ideas how to overcome this?

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio Code as your IDE? When adding new type packages I sometimes need to quit the application and close it down entirely before starting it up again. Doing that restart sometimes fixes it. Other than that I'm not sure sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately it seems to be error with Typescipt itself not being to compile rather than VSCode. No worries though, for now I have raised a issue on the Github repo, so hopefully someone can answer there. https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/discussions/61725

Comment: I tried using this library but it seems that there are some missing types. `client_listener` is not available as a key in `renderButton` as an example.